# Get second td of tr using jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get td values of tr.. but unfortunately it's not working.. may be there is something wrong

My html looks like

```
<tr class="dname">
     <td>abc</td>
      <td>value here</td>
</tr>
```

My jquery code is

```
  jQuery(".dname").find("tr td:eq(1)").val();
```

What's wrong in this ?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

jQuery `find()` method returns the descendants of the selected element. You are already selecting the `<tr>` with a class of `dname` and then trying to find a descendant which is also a `<tr>`.

https://api.jquery.com/find/

The following should work:

```
jQuery(".dname").find("td:eq(1)").text();
```

Edit: `text()` instead of `val()` as @freedomn-m pointed out

Comment: sure it's .val()?

Answer (score 17):

Replace n with child no.

```
$(".dname td:nth-child(n)").text();
```

For e.g. for 2nd child

```
$(".dname td:nth-child(2)").text();
```

Answer (score 5):

You're already filtering on the `tr` by its class name, so there's no need to find by `tr` again.

```
jQuery(".dname").find("td:eq(1)").text()
```

Also, you need to `.text()` to get the contents of a `<td>` not `.val()`.

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/habodofopi/edit?html,js,output) here.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Because that `<td>` is the last child of your `<tr>` you can access it like below,

`jQuery(".dname > td:last-child").text();`

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to point out that if you want some particular value inserted in the cell then do the following (for example if you need to show the text TEST in the table cell):

$(".dname td:nth-child(n)").text("TEST");